# Laravel validation rules for related checkboxes

Tags: laravel, validation, checkbox

In my form I have a couple checkboxes and i want at least one of them (or both) to be checked before submitting my form. My input checkboxes are named `car` and `bike`. In my controller i am validating my request

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'content'=> 'required',
            'title' => 'required',
            'car | bike' => 'required', //this is not correct.
        ]);
```

What i couldn't figure is the statement that allows me to do the validation above

Answer (score 1):

```
return Validator::make($request, [
        'firstName' => 'required|max:255',
        'lastName' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        'checkbox' =>'required_without_all',
    ]);
```

**OR**

```
 return Validator::make($request, [
        'firstName' => 'required|max:255',
        'lastName' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        'option' =>'accepted'
    ]);
```

**OR**

```
Validator::make( 
        [ 'cats' => Input::get('cats') ],
        [ 'cats' => 'min:1' ]
    );
```

**Examples**:

```
$validator = Validator::make([
    'cats' => ['Boots', 'Mittens', 'Snowball']
    ], ['cats' => 'min: 1']);

$result = $validator->fails(); // returns false

$validator = Validator::make([
    'cats' => ['Boots', 'Mittens', 'Snowball']
    ], ['cats' => 'min: 2']);

$result = $validator->fails(); // returns false

$validator = Validator::make([
    'cats' => ['Boots', 'Mittens', 'Snowball']
    ], ['cats' => 'min: 4']);

$result = $validator->fails(); // returns true
```

**OR**

Refer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#available-validation-rules